# Python, debera preguntar nombre, apellido, edad y dirección. los elementos del textfield deben ser enviados a la terminal

Tags: python

Responde con programa y captura de un formulario gráfico hecho en python, debera preguntar nombre, apellido, edad y dirección. los elementos del textfield deben ser enviados a la terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Te dare un codigo con la libreria "Tkinter" (Si no es con esta libreria solo dilo y tratare de investigar);

```
from tkinter import *

class Cuestionario (Tk):
    
    def mostrar_datos(self):
        datos = f"Nombre: {self.nombre_field.get()}.\nApellido: {self.apellido_field.get()}.\nEdad: {self.edad_field.get()}.\nDireccion: {self.direccion_field.get()}."
        # La f es porque es un f-string y todos los valores que esten entre llaves ("{" y "}") seran agregados al string en donde fueron puestos.
        # Y el metodo get es de los Entry y sirve para obtener el texto que halla sido escrito en el Entry.
        
        # Y finalmente mostramos los datos
        print(datos)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.title("Cuestionario")

        # El TextField del nombre
        self.nombre_field = Entry(self)
        # Lo del "self" como argumento del Entry es para que sea de esta ventana (a no ser es que tengas una/s subventana/s es opcional)
        self.nombre_field.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        # El column seria como el X y el row seria como el Y, el padx es la distancia que se achica de su espacio en su column, y el pady es lo mismo pero con el row. Basicamente el padx y el pady es la distancia que se separa de lo que tenga al lado; el padx en X y el pady en Y.

        # Textfield del apellido
        self.apellido_field = Entry(self)
        self.apellido_field.grid(column=0,row=1,padx=5,pady=(0,5))
        # El pady ahora es una tupla; el primer valor es la distancia que tiene hacia arriba el segundo valor es la distancia que tiene hacia abajo.

        # El Textfield de la edad
        self.edad_field = Entry(self)
        self.edad_field.grid(column=0,row=2,padx=5,pady=(0,5))
        # Para remplazar el grid tambien se pueden utilizar los metodos pack y place, pero no los uso porque me parecen un poco mas dificiles, y con el grid queda mas como para un cuestionario.

        # Y el Textfield de la direccion
        self.direccion_field = Entry(self)
        self.direccion_field.grid(column=0,row=3,padx=5,pady=(0,5))

        # Y un boton que hara que todos los datos sean mostrados en la terminal
        self.enviar_datos = Button(self,text="Mostrar datos",command=self.mostrar_datos)
        # Text es el texto que tiene el boton, y command es el metodo/funcion que se llamara cuando el boton sea presionado.
        self.enviar_datos.grid(column=0,row=4,padx=5,pady=(0,5))
```

Perdon si puse demasiados comentarios, pero es para que sea mas entendible, espero que te haya servido y saludos.

Comment: Ayúdanos a mantener la calidad de la información en el sitio, respondiendo a preguntas realizadas de acuerdo a [ask], para responder en el sitio revisa [amswer], saludos.